# What is the best way to create FTP server in Azure?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-blob-storage, hosting, web-hosting

I have a .NET application which needs to read a file which will be sent from another user with FTP credentials.

I am trying to avoid creating VM with Windows, because it might get pricy for our needs.

Can I create Azure Blob Storage and allow access to it with FTP? Would that be cheaper?

Is there more appropriate way to achieve the same result?
Maybe another cloud provider for cheaper VM or other Azure services?

Please share your ideas or alternatives.

Thank you

Comment: Please take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support

Comment: I'll second that, We've been using SFTP support in Azure Storage for a while now and are very pleased with it.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Using the SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) support for Azure Blob Storage is the simplest, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support

There are some limitations listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-known-issues

There are other SFPT servers on the Azure Marketplace, the ones I checked were not cheaper. The easiest way to avoid extra costs is just to turn it one when you need to transfer files.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question; SFTP isn't FTP, they are entirely different protocols. Given a VNET and point-to-point FTP is just as secure as SFTP and while it's 50 years old it's still in common usage (note: FTP should be avoided, and SFTP is superior in pretty much everyway but sometimes legacy systems need to be accommodated)